# Android Circle Menu Like Catch Notes

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, android-custom-view

[image: Catch Notes App]

I try to do circle menu like in this app.

In "expanded" mode i draw this component like follows:

```
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/bigCircle">
<!--color full borders-->
    <my.custom.component android:id="@+id/middleCircle">
    <!--circle for buttons-->
         <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/smallCircle">
           <!--minus button-->
         </RelativeLayout>
    </my.custom.component>
</RelativeLayout>
```

In onDraw method of `my.custom.component` i divide circle on 8 parts by using `android.graphics.Path` with `android.graphics.Paint` and some math. 
Visually i have exactly as shown in the screenshot. But when i press on part of circle, i need redraw this part in another color to show user what something going on.

How i can redraw part of component's canvas  cutting off  from another part of canvas by `android.graphics.Path` for example.
 In another word i know what redraw canvas i should do in onDraw method, i know that i can show some bitmap from drawables painted in photoshop and have some "multiscreen trouble", i know how i can determine part which user pressed. But i don't know how i can select part of canvas and redraw it.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Developer of Catch here. If I'm understanding your issue, you're having trouble understanding how to specifically draw the highlight/selection indicator on a section of your circular menu.

While there are plenty of different ways one could implement it, what you're leaning towards (using `android.graphics.Path`) is how we did it. In the view hierarchy of our capture button, there's an element that serves as the canvas on which the selection highlight color (if there *is* an active selection) is drawn.

If you had a similar custom `View` in your layout, you could duplicate this behavior like so. First, you'll need the `Path` that defines the selection for a particular circle segment. Using `Path.addArc(RectF, float, float)` we can get the pizza-slice-shaped path we need:

```
private Path getPathForSegment(float startAngle, float sweep) {
    Point center = new Point(getWidth() / 2, getHeight() / 2);
    RectF rect = new RectF(0f, 0f, getWidth(), getHeight());
    Path selection = new Path();
    selection.addArc(rect, startAngle, sweep);
    selection.lineTo(center.x, center.y);
    selection.close();
    return selection;
}
```

The `getWidth()` and `getHeight()` above are for the enclosing custom view object, so they define the bounding box that contains the circle on which the selection is drawn.

Then, in your custom view's `onDraw(Canvas)`, if your code has determined a selection should be drawn for a segment:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    // Assume one has the rest of these simple helper functions defined
    if (shouldDrawSelection()) {
        float startAngle = getStartAngleOfSelectedSegment();
        float sweep = getSweepAngle();
        Paint paint = getPaintStyleForSelectedSegment();
        Path path = getPathForSegment(startAngle, sweep);
        canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
    }

    // ...

    super.onDraw(canvas);
}
```

In the other areas of your code that are tracking touches, just call `invalidate()` on the custom view so that it will redraw (or not) the selection path based on changes in input or state.

Remember that it's good practice to avoid `new`ing objects in `onDraw()`, so most of these building blocks (`Path`s, `Paint`s, etc.) can be constructed ahead of time (or once, on first occurrence) and reused.

Hope this is close to what you were asking!

Comment: Now i am back to investigate this question. I even not expected get answer, thanks a lot for `Developer of Catch` you rock. You made very beautiful app.