# Selectable circular imageview like Google+

Tags: android, graphics, imageview

How can I create a selectable circular `ImageView` like in the current Google+ app used for the profile pictures?

This is what I refer to:

[image: Example]

The image above is unselected and the below is selected.

I try to replicate the profile pictures 1 to 1.

**My work so far:**

`loadedImage` is the `Bitmap` which is displayed

```
mImageView.setBackground(createStateListDrawable());
mImageView.setImageBitmap(createRoundImage(loadedImage));
```

The used methods:

```
private Bitmap createRoundImage(Bitmap loadedImage) {
    Bitmap circleBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(loadedImage.getWidth(), loadedImage.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    BitmapShader shader = new BitmapShader(loadedImage, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setShader(shader);

    Canvas c = new Canvas(circleBitmap);
    c.drawCircle(loadedImage.getWidth() / 2, loadedImage.getHeight() / 2, loadedImage.getWidth() / 2, paint);

    return circleBitmap;
}

private StateListDrawable createStateListDrawable() {
    StateListDrawable stateListDrawable = new StateListDrawable();

    OvalShape ovalShape = new OvalShape();
    ShapeDrawable shapeDrawable = new ShapeDrawable(ovalShape);
    stateListDrawable.addState(new int[] { android.R.attr.state_pressed }, shapeDrawable);
    stateListDrawable.addState(StateSet.WILD_CARD, shapeDrawable);

    return stateListDrawable;
}
```

The size of the `ImageView` is `imageSizePx` and the size of the image is `imageSizePx - 3`. So, that means the background should overlap the image. Which doesn't work.

Comment: Got a screenshot of what you're referring to?

Comment: maybe this will help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13108803/android-circle-menu-like-catch-notes

Comment: @CommonsWare Wait a minute.

Comment: image buttons? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3914329/round-button-in-android

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Really simple solution, thanks to @CommonsWare for the tips.

Size of `Bitmap`: imageSizePx - 3DP 
Size of `ImageView`: imageSizePx

```
mImageView.setBackground(createStateListDrawable(imageSizePx));
mImageView.setImageBitmap(loadedImage);

private StateListDrawable createStateListDrawable(int size) {
    StateListDrawable stateListDrawable = new StateListDrawable();

    OvalShape ovalShape = new OvalShape();
    ovalShape.resize(size, size);
    ShapeDrawable shapeDrawable = new ShapeDrawable(ovalShape);
    shapeDrawable.getPaint().setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.somecolor));

    stateListDrawable.addState(new int[]{android.R.attr.state_pressed}, shapeDrawable);
    stateListDrawable.addState(new int[]{android.R.attr.state_focused}, shapeDrawable);
    stateListDrawable.addState(new int[]{}, null);

    return stateListDrawable;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that by "selectable" you mean "checkable, like a `CheckBox`", then that could be some `CompoundButton` that is using a `StateListDrawable` with regular and checked states for the background behind the "SkillOverflow" foreground image.

You can use **`uiautomatorviewer`** to see what the actual widget is that Google+ uses.

Comment: With selectable I mean, that I have touch feedback. I use the term selectable, because the default xml is also named `selectable_background_holo`. Sorry for confusion.

Comment: @Leandros: Then it is probably an `ImageButton` with a custom `StateListDrawable` for the background.

Comment: Most likely. The issue is, how to create the effect as in  the example above? That only a stroke of the circular shape appears there and not the whole rectangle ImageButton / ImageView is highlighted.

Comment: @Leandros: That would be the custom `StateListDrawable` for the background that I've been mentioning. What makes a button look like a button is its background, and that background is rendered with different images for different states (normal, pressed, selected, checked, etc.).

Comment: Yeah, sure. Thats a good idea, before I thought of making the `ImageView` circular, but a circular `StateListDrawable` which is just about 2 pixels wider is a better idea. Now how to make a programmitically scaled `StateListDrawable`?

Comment: @Leandros: Use a `ShapeDrawable` where possible.

Comment: Ok, I created a StateListDrawable with circular shapes, but when I set my image via `setImageBitmap` the image is always the same width / height as the `ImageView`.

Comment: @Leandros: Sounds like you need to add some padding.

Comment: Yep, I did, but it doesn't worked as expected. The padding is completely ignored. I set the padding on the `ImageView` directly.

Comment: @Leandros: You might consider opening another question, supplying your work so far, and demonstrating the flawed results that you are getting.

Comment: My Edit is above in the question.

Answer (score 2):

You can make a custom View that extends ImageView. Override onDraw to clip the canvas with a circular region and draw the image on the canvas. Something like this as a starting point:

```
public class CircularImageView extends ImageView {
    /* constructors omitted for brevity ... */

    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        int saveCount = canvas.save();

        // clip in a circle

        // draw image
        Drawable d = getDrawable();
        if (d != null) {
            d.draw(canvas);
        }

        // do extra drawing on canvas if pressed

        canvas.restoreToCount(saveCount);
    }
}
```

Take some time to get familiar with the Canvas and other 2D drawing APIs in Android.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve this effect through a custom ImageView by overriding `onDraw` and painting some sort of "border" whenever it detects a touch event. As a bonus, there is a selector overlay. Hopefully you may find this view helpful...

https://github.com/Pkmmte/CircularImageView

[image]

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView

Best library so far, super easy to integrate. It will give you border width and color option, you can change the color onClick to match your query.