# How to Make an ImageView in Circular Shape?

Tags: android, imageview

I want to do something like that.

[image: image in List view]

This is a list view row with name and the image of user.

I have done some searching and have done the image circular,but not the perfect solution.
 Any help will be helping me.

my code added to the Image Loader class

```
public Bitmap processBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
    int pixels = 0;
    if (mRound == 0)
        pixels = 120;
    else
        pixels = mRound;
    Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(),
            bitmap.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

    final int color = 0xff424242;
    final Paint paint = new Paint();
    final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
    final RectF rectF = new RectF(rect);
    final float roundPx = pixels;

    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
    paint.setColor(color);
    canvas.drawRoundRect(rectF, roundPx, roundPx, paint);

    paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_IN));
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, rect, rect, paint);

    return output;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please refer to these questions [stackOverflow - question 1](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16922732/1932105) [stackOverflow - question 2](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16208365/1932105) [stackOverflow - question 3](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14179993/1932105) & specially this answer for clicking [stackOverflow - answer 1](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16926721/1932105) they're gonna help you a lot in achieving what you want.

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/5882430/1554935

Answer (score 10):

This probably won't answer your question, but, as an alternative you could mimic that effect by having 2 ImageViews in a `FrameLayout` for example: one at the bottom - this will be the picture, and one on top - this will be the a gray square with a circle in middle, and the "body" of cirle to be transparent.

This way you won't have to do any bitmap processing. But, choose the one that suits better for your needs.

Comment: With this solution you need to know the background color and it must be a unique color without gradient or anything.

Comment: See the following link for an example on how to do this.  http://www.techrepublic.com/article/pro-tip-round-corners-on-an-android-imageview-with-this-hack/

Answer (score 6):

This is accomplished thanks for the reply.

```
Bitmap circleBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setStrokeWidth(5);
Canvas c = new Canvas(circleBitmap);
 //This draw a circle of Gerycolor which will be the border of image.
c.drawCircle(bitmap.getWidth()/2, bitmap.getHeight()/2, bitmap.getWidth()/2, paint);
BitmapShader shader = new BitmapShader(bitmap, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
paint.setAntiAlias(true);
paint.setShader(shader);
// This will draw the image.
c.drawCircle(bitmap.getWidth()/2, bitmap.getHeight()/2, bitmap.getWidth()/2-2, paint);
```

[image]

Rounded image Using imageLoader github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader 
Create a Options;

```
 DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
 // this will make circle, pass the width of image 
.displayer(new RoundedBitmapDisplayer(getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.image_dimen_‌​menu))) 
.cacheOnDisc(true) 
.build(); 
imageLoader.displayImage(url_for_image,ImageView,options);
```

Or U can user Picasso Library from squre.

```
Picasso.with(mContext).load(URL+b.image)
 .placeholder(R.drawable.profile) 
    .error(R.drawable.profile) 
    .transform(new RoundedTransformation(50, 4)) 
    .resizeDimen(R.dimen.list_detail_image_size, R.dimen.list_detail_image_size) 
    .centerCrop() 
    .into(v.im_user);
```

you can download RoundedTrasformation [file here](http://dropbox.com/s/lp3d43hra3gbhul/RoundedTransformation.java)

IMPORTANT:
  i found one issue when using UIL. If you didn't put the xml attribute   android:contentDescription="TODO" in ImageView. Then UIL show simple image.
Hope all understand

Comment: check it out: http://androidtutorialbd.blogspot.co.il/2013/08/circle-imageview-extend-imageview.html?showComment=1399528351106#c6416608644566007267

Comment: Rounded image Using imageLoader https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

Create a Options;
DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
// this will make circle, pass the width of image
        .displayer(new RoundedBitmapDisplayer(getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.image_dimen_menu)))

        .cacheOnDisc(true)
        .build();

imageLoader.displayImage(url_for_image,ImageView,options);

Comment: Or U can user Picasso Library from squre.


Picasso.with(mContext)
.load(com.app.utility.Constants.BASE_URL+b.image)
.placeholder(R.drawable.profile)
.error(R.drawable.profile)
.transform(new RoundedTransformation(50, 4))
.resizeDimen(R.dimen.list_detail_image_size, R.dimen.list_detail_image_size)
.centerCrop()
.into(v.im_user);


you can download RoundedTrasformation file here
https://www.dropbox.com/s/lp3d43hra3gbhul/RoundedTransformation.java

Comment: @GalRom this one works like a charm. thank you for this one.